# python numpy was installed but throws " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'"

Tags: python, numpy

I have installed numpy on ubuntu. it works fine on terminal but when i want to import it to my working directory its shows me this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "", line 1, in 
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Comment: can you add your code along with your question

Comment: how did you install numpy on ubuntu?

Comment: Have you multiple Python versions on your computer and numpy is only in one of them installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

Also this

```
sudo pip install spyder (numpy is included)
```

or

```
sudo easy_install numpy
```